# Github squash commits from web interface on pull request after review comments?

Tags: git, github, workflow

Let's say I have a commit history with 5 commits. I know that I can rebase my commits locally when making a pull request which will then have them rebased into a single commit.

A common use case for this is:

- Make local commits, working on feature
- Squash commits
- Make Pull Request
- Receive review comments
- Update PR appropriately

I can do this locally on my machine and then push my change again (using -f since the rebase makes it out of sync with the remote). This is kind of annoying.

However, this requires that I do a rebase *every* time I address review comments - is there any way I can do this from the web interface?

Or maybe my workflow is wrong, should I be amending each of my "review comments" commits directly onto the main PR commit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to do any rebase/squashing locally anymore: just push your commit to your PR branch.

The owner of the original repo, if he/she chose to, will squash those commits for you (since March 2016):

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/squash-and-merge.png]

See "[Squash your commits](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)" and [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merge-squashing/): it does allow for a new workflow, both for you the contributor, and the maintainer of the original repo.

As I comment below: it will be implemented like the merge of a PR is implemented:

- If it works without conflict, the merge (or here, the `merge --squash`: see "[In git, what is the difference between `merge --squash` and `rebase`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309)") will be created automatically.
- If there is any conflict, the merge is not created, and the maintainer has the option to reject for now the PR, asking the contributor to do the work of squashing the commits and amending the PR.

This is really like what exists now, except GitHub has added the `--squash` to their merge command. Nothing more.

Comment: We were talking about this at work yesterday - it must not be an April Fools prank? :) I'm curious how it will work, because if it is basically rebasing then it will require all your intermediate commits to successfully rebase automatically (and not require manual merging). If it just takes "final state" vs "initial state" and does a diff? That's be good.

Comment: @enderland It is not an april fool indeed! GitHub must be listening after the https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github episode.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just concerned it will not work well in practice if it is doing a rebase/squash operation...

Comment: @enderland it will work well in practice, as it will produce only one commit added to the main branch.

Comment: I know that's the end result. But how will it be implemented? Is it doing an automatic `git rebase --squash master`? Or is it doing a more complex patch or diff process? Some of those will work better than others. Will it result in a "cannot squash, merge conflicts" situation if it doesn't work automatically?

Comment: @enderland it will be implemented like the merge of a PR is implemented. If it works without conflict, the merge (or here, the `merge --squash`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2427520/6309) will be created automatically. If there is any conflict, the merge is not created, and the maintainer has the option to reject for now the PR, asking the contributor to do the work of squashing the commits and amending the PR. This is really like what exists now, except GitHub has added the `--squash` to their merge command. Nothing more.

Comment: Ah, neat! I didn't realize the intricacies of those differences in your other question - thanks for linking that too.

Comment: @enderland No problem. I have included that comment in the answer for more visibility.