# How to delete github repository commit history in web browser

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to delete commit history in github repository inside web browser (without using git).

Comment: Yes you can follow this [link][1] and do all the step from your github repository


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/6947332

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete files](https://help.github.com/en/articles/deleting-files) or [delete branch](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository#deleting-a-branch) from the GitHub Web GUI, but you cannot delete individual commits.

You could try an artificial pull request [followed by a merge and squash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377634/6309), but that might not fit your particular need.

Comment: Would the artificial pull request followed by a merge and squash delete the commits and remove my stars, forks and watchers?

Comment: @JakeLeroy it depends what you actually mean  by deleting the commits: stars and watches are associated to a repository, not commits: do you need to actually delete a repository?

Comment: I was wondering if deleting commits would effect the repositories stars, watches and forks. (I'm talking about commits to a repository)

Comment: No, that should not influence those metadata (star, watcher, ...)